# Python Turtle - Why does this program not work?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

So, I was making a snake game.
I have the following code:

```py
import turtle as tur;
import random, sys, time;

wn = tur.Screen(); #Screen
wn.setup(width=640, height=320);
wn.bgcolor("#000000")

"""

Instructions

"""
boundary = tur.Turtle();
boundary.hideturtle();
writingInstructions = ("Times New Roman", 30, "bold");
writing = ("Times New Roman", 20, "bold");
time.sleep(2);
boundary.write("Instructions:", font=writingInstructions, align="center");
time.sleep(2);
boundary.write("1. You need to eat the apples.", font=writing, align="center");
time.sleep(2);
boundary.write("2. You must not touch the boundary.", font=writing, align="center");
time.sleep(2);
boundary.write("Press 's' to start...");
def no():
    wn.clear();
wn.onkey(no, 's');
wn.listen();

"""

Code for game

"""
shapeSnake = ((-10, 0), (0, 10), (10, 0), (-10, -10)); 
#Initial shape of the snake declared
playArea = ((-200, 200), (200, 200), (200, -200), (-200, -200)); #Play area declared
tur.register_shape('snake', shapeSnake); #Reigster shape for snake
tur.register_shape('play', playArea); #Register shape for play area
t = tur.Turtle(shape='snake'); #Create snake shape
t.up();
a = tur.Turtle(shape='circle'); #Create apple
a.up();
a.goto(randint(-199, 199), randint(-199, 199));
screen = tur.Turtle(shape='play'); #Create play area
score = 0; #score initialisation

def travel(snakeSpeed): #For snake to move
    t.fd(snakeSpeed);

snakeSpeed = 2;

travel(snakeSpeed)
wn.onkey(t.seth(0), 'Right'); #For "right" button
wn.onkey(t.seth(180), 'Left'); #For "left" button
wn.onkey(t.seth(270), 'Down'); #For "down" button
wn.onkey(t.seth(90), 'Up'); #For "up" button

tx, ty = t.pos();
ax, ay = a.pos();
if (tx == ax) and (tx == ax): #Check if apple is eaten
    a.goto(randint(-199, 199), randint(-199, 199));
    score += 1;
    snakeSpeed += 2;
else:
    if (tx >= 200) or (tx <= -200): #Check if outside boundary in X-axis
        sys.exit();
    elif (ty >= 200) or (ty <= -200): #Check if outside boundary in Y-axis
        sys.exit();

wn.listen();
travel(snakeSpeed);
wn.mainloop();
```

What it does is that just a Turtle window with a black background pops up and stays blank.
If I press `s`, the background colour changes to white and that's all.
I have no idea why this doesn't work.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
<strike>Pls: I need to give this a birthday present tomorrow. If someone could give an immediate response, I would be extremely grateful.</strike>
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) for "urgent" related topics in quesitons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have no idea why this doesn't work.

Let's enumerate the posibilities.  Your consistent use of semicolons (;) indicates a lack of understanding of Python syntax.  This sequence:

```
boundary.write("Press 's' to start...");
def no():
    wn.clear();
wn.onkey(no, 's');
wn.listen();

"""
Code for game
"""
shapeSnake = ((-10, 0), (0, 10), (10, 0), (-10, -10));
```

implies you expect `onkey()` to wait for the 's' key to be pressed before the program goes on.  This is not the case, it goes on immediately.  Here you're passing the result of a call to `t.seth()`, i.e. `None`, instead of a function to be called later:

```
wn.onkey(t.seth(0), 'Right'); #For "right" button
wn.onkey(t.seth(180), 'Left'); #For "left" button
wn.onkey(t.seth(270), 'Down'); #For "down" button
wn.onkey(t.seth(90), 'Up'); #For "up" button
```

This is a misunderstanding of how to set up event handlers.  What we expect is something more like:

```
wn.onkey(lambda: t.seth(90), 'Up')  # For "up" button
```

This scoring and boundary checking code appears at the top level of the file and is only executed once:

```
tx, ty = t.pos();
ax, ay = a.pos();
if (tx == ax) and (tx == ax): #Check if apple is eaten
    a.goto(randint(-199, 199), randint(-199, 199));
    score += 1;
    snakeSpeed += 2;
else:
    if (tx >= 200) or (tx <= -200): #Check if outside boundary in X-axis
        sys.exit();
    elif (ty >= 200) or (ty <= -200): #Check if outside boundary in Y-axis
        sys.exit();
```

We'd expect this code to be executed after every move, not just once before the snake really gets moving.

There is no code to keep the snake moving in a forward direction.  It moves forward four pixels, in two spurts, at the start of the program and never again.